# Add custom class to bootstrap button

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, button, drop-down-menu

I have, for one part, this code that is part of a bootstrap  button grous dropdown.

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Filter 1</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="caret"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link3</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">link4</a></li>
  </ul>
```

and I have this part of code that "call" a part of the images of the portfolio (originaly it was in a single button)

```
<li class="filter" data-filter="Filter1">
```

What I want, without loose the bootstrap group button format is that when you click in the button, execute the second code, and let the arrow of the dropdown for expanding the dropdown menu only.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
<div class="btn-group">

 <div class="btn btn-default">


    <li class="filter" data-filter="vehicles"><a href="#vehicles">Vehicles</a></li>
</div>
    <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default  dropdown-toggle"><span
class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>
```